# UWSGI not running Django project

Tags: python, uwsgi

I am trying to run this code

> uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data

I am following [this tutorial.](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) But I am getting the below output.

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.2 (64bit) on [Thu Nov  5 04:42:12 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 04 November 2015 16:32:43
os: Linux-3.16.0-52-generic #71~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 17:24:53 UTC 2015
nodename: myproject
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/www/myproject
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 15305
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
```

This is my .ini file

```
plugins = python
chdir           = /var/www/myproject/
module          = myproject.wsgi:application
home            = /var/www/
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /var/www/myproject/uwsgi.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

My code is working with this

```
uwsgi --ini myproject.ini
```

Please help me to solve this puzzle thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine! Did you try connecting nginx? You can ignore the warnings now.

Comment: Done! But no luck. Can you give me a demo of uwsgi.conf from /etc/ini ?

Comment: It seems to work fine! Did you try connecting nginx? You can ignore the warnings now.

Comment: Yes I have tried. The socket file is not creating. So 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: Thanks bro. Problem solved. It's elementary OS pantheon problem. I have tried on cloud. I am success with that. Now I have to fix my local. Thanks again